# How can I personalize an URL path in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, url-pattern

I am trying to build an website which renders some books and the corresponding pages. I want to make possible to access a page like this:

```
path('/<str:book_pk>-<int:book_page>/', views.TestClass.as_view(), name='book-test')
```

I want a user to access it very simple, something like: `mysite.com/5-12/` - which redirects him to the book nr 5 at page 12. The problem is that when I access this page from the website itself, using `href`, the real path becomes:

```
mysite.com/%2F5-13/
```

If I want to write in the browser, the following path: `myste.com/5-13/`, it throws me `404 page not found`, because the real path is `mysite.com/%2F5-13/` . This is pretty obvious, but my question is:

How can I stick to my initial path, and make it possible to be accessed via `myste.com/5-13/`? For some reason, Django URL Patterns, adds an extra `%2F` string at the beginning. Can somebody explain me why, and how to solve this issue?

I much appreciate your time and effort! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to include `/` at the beginning of the url, simply:

```py
path('<str:book_pk>-<int:book_page>/', views.TestClass.as_view(), name='book-test')
```

`/` is encoded automatically as %2F in urls (read the full list [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm))

Comment: Wow man..oh.. how in the world I missed that... Thank you so so much!  It was a newbie mistake...